# How to fix a working script to be able to use it in multiple directories?

Tags: powershell, subdirectory, organization

Let me start off by saying this place is a great resource and it has helped me develop a well working script, I am looking into expanding it and I am having some trouble doing so.

So, basically I am able to organize a directory with log files into multiple directories based on year and month within those years. I can do this to when I point to those directories directory.

What I am looking to do is apply these script to multiple directories, basically hundreds of logs in (each) multiple directories but all those directories within one main directory.

I have tried to apply the script using the foreach cmdlet but it just doesn't seem to work.

```
#--------
# Creation of an "Archive" folder within the root directory of the targeted dir.
# Comments: Archives Folder is created in each targeted directory.
#--------

foreach($folder in (Get-ChildItem '\\drive\software\logstoreage    \directories' -Directory)){
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path ($folder.fullname+"\Archive")
}

#--------
# Organization of Logs into Yearly and Monthly directories.  
# Comments: Folders are created based on the Year capturing logs through the end of 2018. 
#--------

$date = (Get-Date -Month 1 -Day 1 -Year 2019).ToString("01-01-2019")

$files = Get-ChildItem '\\drive\software\logstoreage\directories\SoftwareA' -Recurse | where {$_.lastwritetime -lt $date -and !$_.PsIsContainer} 

$files

$targetPath = '\\drive\software\logstoreage\directories\SoftwareA\Archive'

foreach ($file in $files){
    $year = $file.LastWriteTime.Year.ToString()
    $month = $file.LastWriteTime.Month.ToString()

    $file.Name
    $year
    $month

    $Directory = $targetPath + "\" + $year + "\" + $month

    if (!(Test-Path $Directory)){
        New-Item $directory -type directory
    }

    $file | Move-Item -Destination $Directory
}
```

Comment: Please give a sample set of directories and logs, and the desired outcome of the script. As it is, I'm guessing this doesn't work because you loop through directories, but don't actually do anything except create the archive folder. You need to expand that loop to include the rest of the script, and not hard code things like `$targetdirectory` or the path in your `$files =` line.

Comment: Once you use gci with the `-Directory` parameter and then a gci and a `Where-Object` checking `!$_.PSIsContainer` instead of the gci's `-File` parameter? Also don't cast `$date` a string when you use that var to compare with `LastWriteTime`

Comment: @TheMadTechnician For example, I have Logs stored in the Logstorage directory, the logs are all associated with the software that pertains to them. I have softwareA, SoftwareB, SoftwareC and so on (I have hundreds of these). For example: C:\Logstorage\Windows\SoftwareA\log1.csv; the script works when I point to the directly to the directories but I just don't have the time to type those out one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a loop to get all of the target folders, you just need to include the rest of your script within that loop, and make a few modifications based on it being inside a loop.

```
foreach($folder in (Get-ChildItem '\\drive\software\logstoreage\directories' -Directory)){
    #--------
    # Creation of an "Archive" folder within the root directory of the targeted dir.
    # Comments: Archives Folder is created in each targeted directory.
    #--------
    $ArchiveFolder = New-Item -ItemType directory -Path ($folder.fullname+"\Archive") -Force


    #--------
    # Organization of Logs into Yearly and Monthly directories.  
    # Comments: Folders are created based on the Year capturing logs through the end of 2018. 
    #--------

    $date = Get-Date -Month 1 -Day 1 -Year 2019

    $files = Get-ChildItem $folder -Recurse -File | where {$_.lastwritetime -lt $date -and !$_.PsIsContainer} 

    $files

    $targetPath = $ArchiveFolder.FullName

    foreach ($file in $files){
        $year = $file.LastWriteTime.Year.ToString()
        $month = $file.LastWriteTime.Month.ToString()

        $file.Name
        $year
        $month

        $Directory = $targetPath + "\" + $year + "\" + $month

        if (!(Test-Path $Directory)){
            New-Item $directory -type directory
        }

        $file | Move-Item -Destination $Directory
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks so much and it makes more sense to me now!